# is there any free software for creating textures in cocos 2D?

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.3

I am new to iphone development.I am wroking on a 2D game by using cocos 2D .I am checking whether there is any software which is there for texture creating .when i searched all are paid software like texture packer, zwoptex . I am looking for free software which can be used to create texture.

Comment: texture packer has a free version which you can use. it won't let you use "advanced" features but the basic ones it will.

Comment: I think [shoebox](http://renderhjs.net/shoebox/) will do the trick, its simple and works well with cocos2d.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TexturePacker, SpriteHelper and Zwoptex let you create texture atlases for cocos2d from individual images. They cost less than $20.

The TexturePacker [trial version](http://www.codeandweb.com/texturepacker/download) includes a command line version of TexturePacker that you can use for free. It has fewer features than the Pro version.

The only free alternative is [Zwoptex (Flash)](http://zwopple.com/zwoptex/static/downloads/zwoptex-flashversion.zip) which is hopelessly outdated, not efficient, can only create 1024x1024 atlases and most importantly it can't update existing texture atlases automatically.

If you're looking for a free program to create images, check out [Seashore](http://seashore.sourceforge.net/The_Seashore_Project/About.html) and [Gimp](http://www.gimp.org).

Comment: The price tag on TexturePacker has increased to $50 by now, SpriteHelper is $35.

Answer (score -1):

try this

https://gutils.com/

This is a web-based application. All your data is stored in your browser storage